# Migration to a different Stack Exchange site instead of closing, and thus discouraging the user

Tags: discussion, migration

I just ran across this question in the low quality queue:

[image: Question voted to close]

I get that it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow, but while it is pretty broad, it is not a bad question per se, and it could probably have been migrated to e.g. [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour). Is this (still?) possible?

I haven't seen any migrated questions lately, but then again I haven't been that active. Wouldn't migrating be much better than throwing a couple of downvotes and a deletion at a new user who clearly put some effort into the question, thus risking discouraging him from continuing with his project *and* from ever contributing to Stack Overflow again?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl

Comment: Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: The Golden Rule of Migration for ***any*** site....Don't Migrate Crap

Answer (score 27):

That is nowhere near appropriate for Programmers.

The fact that so many people *think* questions like these are appropriate on Programmers even though they aren't is exactly why you *can't* migrate questions there.

Contrary to your assertion, I also don't see virtually any effort put into this question at all.  It lacks even the most *basic* of research.  (Both into the actual project itself, and also how to post the question to this site.)  He hasn't done virtually anything, designed anything, come up with any meaningful requirements.  I'd be pretty shocked if he spent more than 60 seconds formulating that question.

Comment: I've added the schema he posted for reference. To be honest, I find this to be a very one-sided perspective. For a beginner, they may have put hours or even days into coming up with something like this. Only because for you, as (assuming) an experienced engineer, this is a matter of seconds (which I don't think it is), it shouldn't give anyone the right to be so condescending..

Comment: @fresskoma He certainly didn't spent days writing that question.  If he spent days working on the project he's demonstrated none of that with his question.  What he *has* demonstrated is that he hasn't even read the simple instructions shown to him about what an appropriate question is on this site, or what kinds of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: @fresskoma effort is necessary, but not sufficient

Answer (score 22):

This is one of the reasons that Programmers.SE is [going to be changing its name](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8204/54997) to Software Engineering; to hopefully avoid moments of thought in which this sort of question might even remotely appear on-topic there.

But look at this question.  It's *terrible*.  It's as if it were ripped out of the [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) example.

"How do I build X" is ***never*** a suitable topic for any network site since X is so infinitely quantifiable, no single answer could ever contain enough information in it to be satisfactory.  If they had a question about X which was significantly more narrow in scope (such as an issue querying some data out of their database, and they provided a basic schema and their query), then I could see a potentially good question coming out of it, but that **wasn't** what was being displayed here.

Lastly - we don't want to migrate crap, and this definitely qualifies as that.  If you see questions that read similar to this, downvoting, voting to close, and even deletion are the right decisions here.

Comment: I just declined a flag for migration to Programmers that came because someone left this comment on a question: "This does seem primarily opinion based. There is a SE site for general programming here: programmers.stackexchange.com which may be more appropriate." I'm really hoping the name change helps.

Comment: @BradLarson you might be interested to know that after site name (and URL) change Thomas Owens [plans to post a feature request](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8196/new-site-name-and-help-center-phase-i-complete#comment25585_8196 "discussed in more details here") to add "programmers.stackexchange" to list of patterns triggering single flag deletion of comments at SO

Answer (score 8):

Migration should be for good content that is just off-topic for the site that was asked. It is still done but community drive migration is limited to a small list of sites.  Open migration to any site can only be done by moderators.

The question you linked is not considered "good content".  It is a horrible question for any SE site because it is much too open ended and broad. It can't reasonably be answered by anyone.  It is more suitable for a site that permits open ended discussions on the best ways to accomplish specific tasks.

By allowing migration regardless of quality, you now force 2 different communities to clean up the poor quality question.